# Solr - use 64-bit Java, not 32-bit Java on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: java, windows-7, solr, 32bit-64bit

I have a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I have Java Runtime Environment for both 32-bit and 64 bit installed on the machine. How do I tell Solr to use the 64-bit version of JRE when I start up Solr?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are running Solr in Tomcat: Set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to the 64-bit version of Java instead of the 32-bit. Then execute `startup.bat` in Tomcat.

Other servlet containers should also be observing the JAVA_HOME environment variable, but I cannot speak for any other than Tomcat.

Comment: This is right for Tomcat, but I don't agree with "Other servlet containers should also be observing the JAVA_HOME environment variable." JAVA_HOME is not standard. There's no reason to expect applications to use it.

Comment: @erickson While not officially standardized, I do believe that `JAVA_HOME` is more or less standard, in that it is used by many applications when the location of the JDK installation folder is necessary. The other option for a program startup script would be to just attempt to call `java.exe` and hope its on the PATH.

Comment: I am using the Jetty web server, not Tomcat. Thanks for your suggestions but I have posted an answer to my own question below.

Answer (score 1):

If, by, start up SOLR you mean start Tomcat with the solr.war installed, then your question is really about how to tell Tomcat to use 64 bit java.  I don't have the answer exactly, but I think you can just edit the catalina.bat file.  In any case, Google for Tomcat + 64-bit java and see what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. But I found out what I did wrong. By starting up Solr, I meant running the 'java -jar start.jar' command with the Windows Command Prompt. To start up Solr using the 64-bit JRE, you have to use the Windows Command Prompt for 64-bit. I wasn't aware of two different versions of the Windows Command Prompt (32-bit and 64-bit).